# create a connected graph by just using latitude and longitude

Tags: java, graph, geolocation

I want to build a directed graph(to use Depth First Search) using the city location (latitude,longitude) in Java. I have the city coordinates which can server as nodes but do not have the data pertaining to city connectivity(for edges). From where can I get the data and how to build the graph? Is there an alternate to use DFS directly on a map?

Thanks in advance!!

*Edit-->* **The problem in detail**-
I have a list of cities along with their geo-coordinates. I want to create a graph from the cities (which will serve as vertices) to run some algorithms such as DFS, BFS, etc. By connectivity I meant a physical path connecting 1 city to other by road. 
For example, there are 6 cities a,b,c,d,e,f. I want to traverse from a->e but there is no direct road. So on map, I would select the intermediate points and route would be like a->c->d->e. To make a graph from it, I would create 6 vertices and make edges from a->c, c->d and d->e

I my case, to build a graph from the list of cities, I am not sure which city connects to which one. One option is to do it manually and plot the graph. I am looking for an option where I could just give city coordinates and it would create a connected graph for me.

Comment: What does connectivity mean here? There is a lot less information here than anyone would need to help you. Can you elaborate more? What data are you looking for? Connectivity in a graph can mean any number of things, we dont know what it means to your application so no one can help you find the data you are looking for.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope it is more clear now!

Comment: Its a bit clear but I still have a few questions. I think it might help you to think about what you are asking a bit more. Is it real data you want or simulated data? If its real, I dunno how that would work. Any 2 cities would be connected by some road or the other unless the city was on an island. There probably isnt a dataset like this. The best I could think of was to use google maps to ask for directions and then disregard those where it makes you take the ferry etc. Either way, I am not sure this is a question anyone can actually answer Mayank. I am sorry I wasnt more help.

Comment: No problems Vib! Its the real data I am referring to. I was thinking if it is possible to use OpenSourceMap and plot my points on it and pass it to the Java code to construct the graph?

Comment: When you say plot your points what do you mean? You already have the city names and their coordinates. What would you like to extract from the map that you would like to use?

Comment: I would like to get the road between the cities. So that these roads/paths can be used to create the edges of the graph.

Comment: The edges have distances attached to them ? If yeah this all makes a lot more sense. You could get distances between cities from the internet. What do the edges represent? Distance or just a binary connectivity between 2 cities?

Comment: An edge represents a direct road between two cities. The weight of an edge will represent the time taken to cover the distance.